# covering for sick colleagues

Tags: salary, sickness

I work part time with another person and a full time person. When the full time person is off sick, which could be for weeks, I'm expected to cover for them and work full time? is this correct?
Also when both colleagues are off sick I have been asked to cover for both and do two peoples jobs at the same time, which i have done in the past but working with hot equipment and general public safety, is this acceptable and still get normal pay?

Comment: What does your employee handbook say?

Comment: Do you work in construction? Manufacturing? Were you provided with training, and appropriate safety equipment? Are you aware of your rights as an employee, both in terms of company policies, as well as labor legislation in your country/state? You're not giving us much to go on here.

Comment: work in the catering business, full training has been given. employees handbook says i should cover for sickness but it doesnt say anything about full time when im only working part time.

Comment: We lack a lot of information, and this your answer will probably be written somewhere either in the contract, the company rules, or the employee rulebook.

Comment: @steve, thanks for the clarifications. I'm assuming that when you pick up extra hours, they pay you for those. I'm also assuming that when 2 co-workers are sick and you are picking up the slack for them, they are not paying you extra. As long as they are not violating any laws, what is "correct" and "acceptable" is what ever you allow them to get away with. If you are part-time and can't pick up the extra hours, tell them. If 2 co-workers are sick and you have to pick up the slack, talk to your boss about it. Surely he/she realizes.

Comment: What does your boss say?

Answer (score 4):

Your contract will state what your working hours are although, if it's anything like mine (and the 6 or 7 before that) it will say something along the lines of "may be changed as per the needs of the business" which is a standard get out clause for this kind of thing.

Should your employer expect you to suddenly work full time when you're on a part time contract?  No.  There's usually a reason (child care, elderly relative, secretly an international spy) why you've taken a part time job and it is unfair of them to do so.

So, what can you do about it?  If they're paying you for the extra hours, you could just say thank you very much and pocket the extra cash.  Equally, you could say that your contracted hours are such and such and only work those hours.

I've been in a similar situation with someone leaving the company unexpectedly so I told them what extra hours I could work around my other responsibilities and that is all I could do.  They appreciated that I did extra while a more permanent solution was found and everything returned to normal when staffing levels did.

Comment: Good answer. You go part-time for a reason. Sometimes you can help out with a few extra hours here and there. Sometimes you can't.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that's right on the part of the company to burden a single person for the cause of other employees.According to me Your income must be proportional to your work done which means if you are asked to work double then you must be payed in that way too.
It must be on you if you want to work and help your sick colleague while the company cannot order you to do so as you won't be payed for that.
You can take legal action too depending on your countries law ,if you are forced to do so.
According to me the only reason for you to do your colleagues work would be to help them.So it depends on your relation with your colleague.And considering your catering business you can help your colleague with a little more burden on your shoulders,but no one can force you to do so.